# FadeIn and fadeOut on the following demo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

After trying several options, I couldn't make the text fade in and out.
Whatever I try, the whole animation just freezes, even when adding something like this

```
$("#headertxt".fadeIn('slow').css({"display" : "block"});
```

or

```
$("#headerimg" + currentContainer).fadeOut(function() {
setTimeout(function() {
$("#headertxt".fadeIn({"display" : "block"}); 
animating = false;
}, 500);
});

$("#headerimg" + currentContainer).fadeOut(function() {
setTimeout(function() {
$("#headertxt".fadeOut({"display" : "block"}); 
animating = false;
}, 5000);
});
```

This is the original [demo](http://demo.marcofolio.net/bgimg_slideshow/)

And [here's jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HELLena/QxAKa/)

Comment: You should work on reducing the code in your question to a barebones example. http://sscce.org/

Comment: Could you cut your fiddle down to just the part you are asking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$("#headertxt".fadeIn('slow').css({"display" : "block"}); //this will not work
```

to

```
$("#headertxt").fadeIn('slow', function(){
  $(this).css('display', 'block');
});
// apply css after animation.
```

Comment: jQuery sets `display` to `block` on conclusion of the `fadeIn` anyway.

Comment: @Blazemonger correct, I added that css part in callback just to say, normally you should apply css after animation.
And also '#headertxt' can be an inline element, which maybe you want to convert to block element.

Comment: @HamidRaza thanks that was it for fadeIn, but now I cannot set the fadeOut

Comment: @Lena try $("#headertxt").fadeIn('slow'); //don't use css dispaly none

Answer (score 0):

fadeIn and fadeOut don't take objects as arguments, so I'm not sure why you have those. You're also missing a parenthesis before `.fadeIn`.

Try something like this:

```
$("#headerimg" + currentContainer).fadeOut(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#headertxt").fadeIn(); 
        animating = false;
    }, 500);
});
```